# currency format not working for south african RAND using JasperReports Server

Tags: java, jasper-reports, currency, jasperserver

I'm using *JasperReports Server 3.7.2* and *iReport 3.7.2*.  I am passing in the locale to *JR Server* as en_ZA. The pattern I'm using for the currency field is `¤ #,##0.00` When I run the report with a value of 1234.25 and with the locale "en_US" the output is `$1,234.25` as expected.  When I use the locale fr_FR the output is €1 234,25 with the comma being used as the symbol, which is expected.  However, when I use the locale of en_ZA I get the proper currency symbol of "R" but the number is being formatted as `R 1,234.25` I was expecting it to be `R 1 234,25` with the comma.

Any ideas why this is not displaying the RAND currency correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok to set your Locale to fr_FR and work with your reports;

Then you can set the pattern to R #,##0.00 instead of ¤ #,##0.00 and get R 1 234,25